# globals are not accessible inside the Multiprocessing python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My application requires to execute some arbitrary python code as an input.
When I try to execute it in the different process using the Multiprocessing module there are some issues with the `globals()` of the code.

Consider the following code which works as expected.

```
src = """import os
    def x():
        print(os.getcwd())"""

exec (src)
eval('x()')
```

This code works as expected without any error.

When I want to execute the same thing with multiprocessing with following code it gives me the error that it can't find the `os` ?

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

src = """import os
def x():
    print(os.getcwd())"""

def my_eval(source):
    try:
        exec (source)
        eval('x()')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

pool.submit(my_eval, src)
```

output in this case is

```
<Future at 0x7fcc4c160f28 state=running>
name 'os' is not defined
```

The answer given by [viethtran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11076781/viethtran) solves the issue for me but can someone explain why do we need to pass `globals` in case of `multiprocessing`  and why not in the case of normal execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I added `globals()` as an argument for the `exec()` function.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

src = """import os
def x():
    print(os.getcwd())"""

def my_eval(source):
    try:
        exec (source, globals())
        eval('x()')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

pool.submit(my_eval, src)
```

Update:
I figured that the reason your reports `name 'os' is not defined` is because the `os` import is somehow put out-of-scope in the function `x` (your code will actually work if I move the `import os` inside the `x` function) so I decided to add `globals()` as an argument so that `exec()` can add the `os` import into `globals()` and will access it when `x` function is called by `eval()`.

If you print out the `globals()` before and after the `exec (source, globals())`, you will notice that module `os` and function `x` will be added to the globals() dictionary.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

src = """import os
def x():
    print(os.getcwd())"""

def my_eval(source):
    try:
        print('==========')
        print(globals())
        print('==========')
        exec(source, globals())
        print('++++++++++')
        print(globals())
        print('++++++++++')
        eval('x()')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

pool.submit(my_eval, src)
```

This code will print out something like this:

```
==========
{'my_eval': <function my_eval at 0x7ff63c7baaa0>, 'ProcessPoolExecutor': <class 'concurrent.futures.process.ProcessPoolExecutor'>, 'src': 'import os\ndef x():\n    print(os.getcwd())', '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'test.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'pool': <concurrent.futures.process.ProcessPoolExecutor object at 0x7ff640c14050>}
==========
++++++++++
{'my_eval': <function my_eval at 0x7ff63c7baaa0>, 'ProcessPoolExecutor': <class 'concurrent.futures.process.ProcessPoolExecutor'>, 'src': 'import os\ndef x():\n    print(os.getcwd())', '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'test.py', '__package__': None, 'x': <function x at 0x7ff63c7bac80>, '__name__': '__main__', 'os': <module 'os' from '/home/viet/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>, '__doc__': None, 'pool': <concurrent.futures.process.ProcessPoolExecutor object at 0x7ff640c14050>}
++++++++++
<your pwd here>
```

Comment: It works but can you explain this extra thing is required inside multiprocessing ?

Comment: I figured that the reason your reports `name 'os' is not defined` is because the `os` import is somehow put out-of-scope in the function `x` (your code will actually work if I move the `import os` inside the `x` function) so I decided to add `globals()` as an argument so that `exec()` can add the `os` import into `globals()` and will access it when `x` function is called by `eval()`.